F is a field of char $0$,F(X) is the field of rational function,why for every rational function $f(X)$ ,$f(X) \neq 0$, $[F(X):F(f(X))]$ is finite?
Proposition: F is a field of char $0$,F(X) is the field of rational function,for every rational function $f(X)$,$f(X) \neq 0$ , $[F(X):F(f(X))]$ is finite.
I Know that we can prove it by letting $f(X)=p(X)/q(X)$,$f(X)q(X)-p(X)=0$,so$[F(X):F(f(X))] \leq  min\{deg\ q(X),deg\ p(X)\}$.
But I want to prove it by Galois theory.Here is my idea.
Consider $Aut(F(X)/F(f(X)))$,and they also fix $F$.So I think every element in $Aut(F(X))/F(f(X))$ is determined by a rational function $h(X)/g(X)$.I only need to prove that there are only finite such rational functions that fix $f(X)$.In fact,if $h_{i}(X)/g_{i}(X)$ is such rational function,we have $\frac{ p(h_{i}(X)/g_{i}(X))}{q(h_{i}(X)/g_{i}(X))}= \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}$.That is $p(h_{i}(X)/g_{i}(X))q(X)-q(X)p(h_{i}(X)/g_{i}(X))=0 $.It can be seen as a polynomial $H(X)=p(t)q(X)-q(t)p(X)$ whose coefficients are polynomials in $F[X]$ and varieties are rational functions.Then we have the number of zeros not more than $min\{deg\ q(X),deg\ p(X)\}$.So we conclude that $|Aut(F(X)/F(f(X)))| \leq min\{deg\ q(X),deg\ p(X)\} .$
I want to know if my idea is right.Thanks.
I think may idea may be wrong.Because $F’=F(X)^{Aut(F(X)/F(f(X)))}\supset F(f(X))$.So I can only get $|Aut(F(X)/F(f(X)))|\leq [F(X):F(f(X))]$.How can I prove  $[F(X):F(f(X))]$ is finite?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

$f(X)$ should be $\ne0$.

Thanks.I have corrected
